# newtxtext package error: realscripts.sty not found

Tags: packages, ubuntu

I'm attempting to use the [mnras](https://ctan.org/pkg/mnras) package to compile a file, but I keep getting the error:

```
TraditionalBuilder: Engine: lualatex. Invoking latexmk... done.

Errors:

/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newtx/newtxtext.sty:472: LaTeX Error: File `realscripts.sty' not found. [      \ifntx@KOMA]

No warnings.
```

I've installed and reinstalled pretty much every package recommended in a dozen different sites to no avail. I'm running a Ubuntu (22.04.2 LTS) based system, how can I solve this please?

---

This basic file is enough to reproduce the issue:

```
\documentclass[fleqn,usenatbib]{mnras}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\VAN}[3]{#2}
\let\VANthebibliography\thebibliography
\def\thebibliography{\DeclareRobustCommand{\VAN}[3]{##3}\VANthebibliography}
\usepackage{graphicx}   % Including figure files
\usepackage{amsmath}    % Advanced maths commands
\title[Short title, max. 45 characters]{Some title}

\author[J. Smith et al.]{
James Smith,$^{1}$\thanks{E-mail: myemail@gmail.com}
\\
$^{1}$Institute of etc
}
\date{Accepted XXX. Received YYY; in original form ZZZ}
\pubyear{2023}
% Don't change these lines
\begin{document}
\label{firstpage}
\pagerange{\pageref{firstpage}--\pageref{lastpage}}
\maketitle

% Abstract of the paper
\begin{abstract}
Abstract
\end{abstract}
\begin{keywords}
keyword1 -- keyword2 -- keyword3
\end{keywords}

\section{Introduction}
Some intro
```

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=realscripts.sty&mode=exactfilename&suite=jammy&arch=any gives [texlive-xetex](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/texlive-xetex)

Comment: Thank you, that worked